# Executing java code given in a text file

Tags: java

I have a set of java code in a text file. Is it possible for me to read line by line from the text file and execute the commands as in eval function of javascript? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Try using [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/). From the introductory page:

> What is BeanShell?
>
> BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable
>   Java source interpreter with object
>   scripting language features, written
>   in Java. BeanShell dynamically
>   executes standard Java syntax and
>   extends it with common scripting
>   conveniences such as loose types,
>   commands, and method closures like
>   those in Perl and JavaScript.
>
> You can use BeanShell interactively
>   for Java experimentation and debugging
>   as well as to extend your applications
>   in new ways. Scripting Java lends
>   itself to a wide variety of
>   applications including rapid
>   prototyping, user scripting extension,
>   rules engines, configuration, testing,
>   dynamic deployment, embedded systems,
>   and even Java education.
>
> BeanShell is small and embeddable, so
>   you can call BeanShell from your Java
>   applications to execute Java code
>   dynamically at run-time or to provide
>   extensibility in your applications.
>   Alternatively, you can use standalone
>   BeanShell scripts to manipulate Java
>   applications; working with Java
>   objects and APIs dynamically. Since
>   BeanShell is written in Java and runs
>   in the same VM as your application,
>   you can freely pass references to
>   "live" objects into scripts and return
>   them as results.
>
> In short, BeanShell is dynamically
>   interpreted Java, plus a scripting
>   language and flexible environment all
>   rolled into one clean package.

Answer (score 3):

No. Java is a compiled language, so this behaviour is impossible unless you invoke the compiler first. (And there is no guarantee that a machine with Java has the Java compiler.)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be easier to start looking for scripting languages, which are very well supported by the Java VM.

[Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) is first to come in mind, it has a Java like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly. It can be done non-trivially using the [compiler API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). But you're really better off writing an XML configuration that controls your program, rather than allow executing arbitrary code in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Janino](http://www.janino.net/) to compile your generated *.java file. After you compiled your file, you can load the *.class file and call a method by reflection.