# How to organize Exception classes without code duplication?

Tags: java

I have a number of custom `Exception`-inheriting classes in my package, which do not differ from their base class. The only purpose I have them is to distinguish one exception cause from the other, when it is thrown. This is how one of my Exception class looks like:

```
package com.XXX;
/**
 * Thrown when query format is invalid.
 */
public class InvalidFormatException extends Exception {
  /**
   * Public ctor.
   * @param m Supplementary message
   */
  public InvalidFormatException(final String m) {
    super(m);
  }
}
```

The problem is that all classes are absolutely identical, like twins. The only thing which is different is their names. I don't like this situation, since it's an obvious code duplication. In other languages (like PHP, Python, etc.) I would declare these classes on-fly during runtime, but Java doesn't allow this, as well as I understand. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create a generic class with a code property settable with the controller. This way you can have only one class and instance when thrown.

That said, I don't agree when you say classes are twins. They represent totally different functional exception. Based on the separation of concerns pattern, the current implementation is the correct one. Using my generic class will mix concerns in your class and that should be forbidden.

Moreover, I see you inherit from Exception... I will not explains a lot but you should use RuntimeException for functional exceptions in your application. Look around on the web, there is a lot of literature about it.

Comment: I disagree that functional exceptions should be unchecked (inherited from `RuntimeException`). Classes are really "semantical twins", because the only difference between them is their name. The rest of the code is absolutely identical and it means "code duplication", which is the major cause of all errors in programming :(

Comment: Vincenzo, for the RuntimeException the discussion is too long to be in this thread. But I know I'm right :). Object orientation aims to create different objects for different concerns. The name of a class should moreover explains its concerns. If you have two classes with different names, I guest it's because they respond to different concerns. If the meaning of two exceptions with different names is the same then you must at least rename them to have similar names. If they are in same package, you can delete one occurence of the your exception class. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is "no", you cannot easily declare on the fly classes with Java. That noted, if you really wanted to do this, it is possible, [you'll need to study how Java can compile classes at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064259/how-can-i-compile-and-deploy-a-java-class-at-runtime). Another simplification is if all your exception classes are the same, excepting their names, you could define a base Exception class of your own that they extend.

Another thought, what value are you getting from having all these different Exception classes? Are you clients going to handle things differently depending on what Exception's thrown? If not, I'd suggest examining the Exception hierarchy you've created and simplifying.

Then, if you go that far, consider using RuntimeException as well. This might be grounds for a holy war, but if you really don't do anything special with what's thrown, there's not much value in forcing you client to deal with it. [See Bruce Eckel's article on the subject for some perspective](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions).