# Singleton clone attack

Tags: java, reflection, singleton, clone

I saw a lot of people implementing the `clone` method for singletons, which are throwing a `CloneNotSupportedException`. Why?

How for example could this be hacked by cloning or any other way?
Btw. I have read effective java and know about enums.

```
public final class Elvis implements Serializable {

    public final static transient Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis();

    private Elvis() {
        if(INSTANCE != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is a singleton. Don't try to instantiate it.");
        }
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        //serialization protection
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise one can create more than one object of your singleton class using cloning.

Comment: The object  class has `clone()` method

Comment: But if there is no interface Cloneable implemented, how would you call that?

Comment: you can add method run time to this class. [how ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime)

Comment: If you can show me an implementation of this method I will believe you.

Comment: Ok, but this only can happen with a patched version of the jvm. Not the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

> ... throwing a CloneNotSupportedException. Why?

You can check out the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
```

> Throws: 
>   CloneNotSupportedException - if the object's class does not support the Cloneable interface. Subclasses that override the clone method can also throw this exception to indicate that an instance cannot be cloned.

Comment: I didn't ask why clone throws a CloneNotSupportedException. I asked, why would anyone implement that method if there is no interface Cloneable implemented anyway?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody trying to implement singleton would also implement the clone method. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't. But I saw a lot of mentions in forums where developers are preventing cloning by implementing clone and throwing an exception. I ask why, because I can't imagine a hack.