# Adding a method to Java class in different file without extending the class

Tags: java, class, function, methods, extends

```
package com.companyxyz.api.person;

public class Man {
    public var1;
    public var2;
    ...
    private static void createAuth() {
    ...
    }
    // public methods go here
    ...
}
```

I want to create a new public method that accesses the private method, *createAuth*, but in a different file.  Is there a way to create this new method without writing it or accessing it via an extended class?

Thank you.

Comment: See the Java tutorial page [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime

Answer (score 5):

No. You can't access a private method from an other class. Because it's ... private.

Comment: I understand that.  I want to "continue" the Man class by adding new methods to it without touching the original file.

Comment: As Duncan Jones says, you can use reflection, but it's another story.

Answer (score 4):

A private method is not accessible to any external classes, (this includes subclasses).

A workaround might be to use reflection, however this isn't a generally recommended approach for a number of reasons (brittleness, performance problems, breaking encapsulation, etc).

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact you're breaking the encapsulation of the member variable, reflection isn't very safe either - most of the methods you're going to use throw a multitude of exceptions (which are difficult to handle correctly) and the security manager, if present, can veto these action too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean and recommended general way to do this in Java. `private` is private.

But you did not state *why* you want to do this and what the *specific constraints* are. Therefore I throw two options into the mix:

- You can decompile the class file for `Man`, set everything you want to protected or public and recompile (and repackage into a jar file). Perhaps there is no need to decompile, perhaps some bit manipulation on the class file can do the job, too.
- You can write a custom `ClassLoader` with a bytecode manipulation library to modify the bytecode of the class at runtime. Then you can also add additional access paths to the stuff you want. Note however that this is *extremely* advanced/complicated stuff.

Both ways are nothing you can use / should use for normal applications or the usual framework.