# Create Fields and methods dynamically

Tags: java

I want to add new fields(variables) and encapsulating methods for a given class. For example: A class name Student has no any fields like below:

```
public class Student implements Serializable{

}
```

then in my application an instance is created;

```
Student s=new Student();
```

I want to add new methods which do not exist for student class at the run time.for example: I want to add a field called `studentName`, and `getStudentName()` and `setStudentName()` methods.

Then at the run time the student object will be like this;

```
public class Student implements Serializable{

    private String studentName;

    public void setStudentName(..){}
    public String getStudentName(){return ...;}
}
```

In my application objects are written to a text file and all objects of same type do not have all variables. Therefore, I want to add only the required fields to save memory.

Any way is there a way to do this? Any sample code or link?

**EDIT:  or else can we create a class either and create instances which does not exists ?**

EDIT 2: Thanks all of you answered and got many info and ideas. And changed the way to a better path from your suggestions as well

Comment: Partial Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime

Comment: It sounds like you may be coming up with a solution to an unfounded concern, and one which could be better addressed with more upfront thought about the data model (and possibly more types).

Comment: Don't follow that road, for God's sake !

Comment: You don't need that, seriously, just don't do it. Ask about how to implement the thing that you want to implement this way

Comment: "In my application objects are written to a text file and all objects of same type do not have all variables" .. what this means??

Comment: it's not possible with pure java but with bytecode manipulation. Nevertheless, I see absolutely no reason from your given post to do so and I wouldn't recommend it either! As other people already said: DON'T DO THIS

Comment: @AashMaharoon, just imagine how you will load those objects from a file without knowing what was stored there. Just save all, and when you'll run out of disk space buy another disk, they're cheap enough

Comment: If your gut keeps telling you to modify classes at runtime, you may want to check out python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just create a `HashMap` of values? Much more efficient, and has all the flexibility you're looking for.

```
public class Student
{
      private HashMap<String, String> values;

      public Student()
      {
          this.values = new HashMap<String, String>();
      }

      public void addValue(String name, String value)
      {
          values.put(name, value);
      }

      public String getValue(String name)
      {
          return values.get(name);
      }
}
```

**Why a HashMap?**

You said that all objects may have differing values, and you'll be defining those new methods and attributes by a `String`. Well.. this will achieve that functionality without any horrible bytecode manipulation. For example:

```
String attrName = "name";
String attrValue = "jim";
Student stu = new Student();
stu.addValue(attrName, attrValue);
```

At the moment, you've only got the one value in your `HashMap`. The only overheard you have to face is the `HashMap` object itself, and two methods, which frankly is a fair trade off for a far tidier solution.

Comment: I think the OP should rather rethink the data model as Jon Skeet suggested in his comments, rather than creating some class that can hold any arbitrary set of attributes.

Comment: Be worry of the memory consumption of the HashMap, perhaps you want to give it a initial capacity estimate at construction.

Comment: I think these details are more for OP to work out. I don't like handing them everything. And agreed Griffey, but if we can achieve their desired functionality, then it makes sense to post it. If anything, so future readers know what to do is this type of class *is* the correct choice.

Comment: You are assuming values are stored as String... anyways if they are needed to be retrieved as a specific type it would be necessary to create parsers with its probably consequent impact in performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use bytecode instrumentation libraries like [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or [ASM](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://asm.ow2.org/&ei=3TMOUs6oNMGCrgfWqoDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEv2IRP-KCv_PInxMBDtMibNLnWlw&bvm=bv.50768961,d.bmk) for this purpose. [Here is an example](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add) of adding a field or method by using Javassist.

Comment: True, but I don't think it is a good idea to follow that route specially for someone that is making such a basic question about Java in the first place.

Comment: Yes. Agree. This was just another option.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible with bytecode manipulation and such it wouldn't be wise, especially if you intend to do this to "save memory". It's unlikely that you would have so much data that it would make a difference, and if you did, you would store them in a database anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own `HashMap` based solution you can use [DynaBean and DynaClass](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean.html): support not only simple properties but also indexed (Array) and mapped (Map).
DynaBean can be introspected to get properties and values so you can dump to file **BUT**
with this solution you are only "simulating" a bean, your `Student` class doesn't really contains fields and accessors (you you call `Student.getClass().getDeclaredField()` you will get an empty array).

If you need to compose a "real" java `java.lang.Class` Javassist (my preferred choice, I used to resolve a solution similar to your question) or ASM (or CGLIB) are the best choiches.

Comment: It's `HashMap` not `HasMap` a minor typo there

Answer (score 0):

*Practically speaking,* not in Java.  In other languages like Javascript, this is possible.

Comment: Reflection can't add fields. You need bytecode manipulation for that.

Comment: You can do that using bycode instrumentation libraries like ASM or Javassist.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe if this is possible in java but I'm sure it will only add to the memory because if you add them dynamically they must be set up beforehand + the code to add them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not a dynamic programming language and so I would not advice to follow that route even if some advance approaches may allow you to do so.

The Java idiom for that scenario would be to store the field values in a (hash) map instead. So you would have a couple of common accessors to set or get all attribute values and in the accessor you would need to indicate the name of the attribute you want to change.

However this solution won't save memory unless the maximum number of attributes is rather large and most object just have values for a small number of such attributes.

```
   public class Entity {
   
      // 5 is an estimate for the number attrs.
      private Map<String,Object> attrs = new HashMap<>(5); 

      public Object getAttribute(String name) { return attrs.get(name); }

      public void setAttribute(String name, Object obj) { attrs.put(name,obj); } 

   }
```

You could implement some runtime type-checking if you manage meta-data about possible attributes and their value types.

Comment: IDEA reports an error here:     `attrs.put(name, obj); `, because ? is unknown type.