# If any way to dynamic add fields in class depends on values from JSON?

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I try to read `Json` file with `Jackson` and depends on it, make another `Json` output. The problem is to read `Json` file, I created a `POJO` object with fields, that represent in `Json`. But it could change and there are could be appear another values, that I didn't represent in `POJO`. So my logic there, is will add fields, depends on read values I've been get from Json. Is there are any way to do this, or I came not right way..

```
public String makeOutput() {

        Collection<String> key = map.get("POJO");

        for (String name : key) {

            requestOut = mock.reflect(CAPM.class)
                    .field("name", "Anna")
                    .field("age", 12)

// there is field 'name', that didn't represent in POJO

                    .field(name, "Green")
                    .map(gson::toJson)
                    .val();

        }

        return requestOut;
    }
```

I'm using `mockNeat` lib. for generate `Json`. "map" is a `MultiValuedMap<String, String>`

Comment: To know which fields are in the JSON file first load the file content into a Map ([Convert json to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map) details how this can be done) and then loop over the map and build the requestOut object as in your example

Comment: @ValentinCarnu It doesn't help. It's no problem to read `Json` and look what fields are there. If I take from it field, that doesn't represent in `JavaBean` class - it shouldn't work.

Comment: To dynamically add fields to a class you will need to use byte code instrumentation libraries, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18275466/10386912) are some details