# How to add properties functions to objects from another class in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, object, properties

In Javascript we can define an object like this

```js
let obj={
    property1:67,
    func1: function (){
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Now if we want add a new property to `obj` I can just add a new property like this

```js
obj.property2=733; //some value or function
```

Now I want to do the same thing in Java also.

I have a class Test

```cpp
public class Test{
    int property1=67;
    public void func1(){
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Now is it possible to do like the same thing like statement #2 in Java also?

**Edit:**
From the answers I got to know that we can use a Map for properties.
Now I want to know for methods.
*Thanks*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Fields and methods dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275360/create-fields-and-methods-dynamically)

Comment: I not only want to add properties like that but methods also.

Comment: It is not possible in java to do that, maybe by altering byte code which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a research and as I can see this is not simple.

In java you can not do that, actually, you can if you provide your own custom class loading, which is really a bad idea because then even if you change the class you want you must reload all classes that interact with this class.

Check [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders) to understand more about class loaders.

Of course, there are some other ways as:

- [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) an all-purpose Java bytecode manipulation and analysis framework.
- [Javassist](https://www.javassist.org/) a library for editing bytecodes in Java
- [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) aspect-oriented extension to the Java, mostly used to clean modularization of crosscutting concerns

Comment: Thank you I'll will surely check out.