# Manipulation of methods from other classes

Tags: java, vector

Can the contains() method from the Vector class in Java be manipulated from another class (without expanding the Vector class)?

Let's say we have this:

```
class AuxType {
    String name;
    int type;

    AuxType(String name, int type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Main {
    void aMethod() {
        Vector<AuxType> v = new Vector<AuxType>();
        v.add(new AuxType("a", 1));
        v.add(new AuxType("b", 2));
        v.add(new AuxType("c", 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v.get(i).type == 2) {
                System.out.println("Found it!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The for/if lines could be written as

```
if (v.contains(2)) {
    //
}
```

Is a way through which I can change how contains() works (either in the AuxType class or in the aMethod() function from Main)?

EDIT: NOT A DUPLICATE

I wasn't asking about calling a method from a class, but about changing it without extending that class.

Comment: You're asking if you can use a method from another class without (a) extending that class, (b) composing an instance of that class, or (c) using some sort of heinous bytecode manipulation? No.

Comment: I wasn't asking about calling a method from a class, but about changing it without extending that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), and no, it's not available in Java.

In Java this problem is solved by using inheritance (and it does make perfectly sense although is somewhat verbose).

Theoretically it is [possible to add a method dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime) without directly defining a new class but it's really complicated and overdone for the task.

Just extend the class or define an utility method.