# How to Inject a Function inside a set of classes

Tags: java, spring

I have a usecase where i want a particular class or a spring bean to be injected in a set of classes that have a particular annotation. Basically i want a few set of methods to be added to the annotated classes.

Suppose i have a class annotated with annotation @Finders. Then i want the class to be able to use some predefined methods like 
`findById()`, `findByName()` etc to be available to the class and we should be able to call these functions in a static context like

`User.findById()` and so on.

Is there a way to inject these methods to the class using Java or Spring. Can i use reflection to do this.

Is there any other way i can get this done in java.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680674/can-a-java-class-add-a-method-to-itself-at-runtime

Comment: Can you use Java 8? This sounds something that implementable interfaces can be useful for. Also, by only reading the title, that is really near to what subclassing provides.

Comment: yes i am open to use java 8

Comment: You're up for an over-engineered world of pain by taking this approach. Subclass of create a static helper class.

Comment: i am actually looking forward to create a orm layer for the elastic search, so that i may be able to use it as a database