# URLClassLOader unable to load classes from jar dynamically

Tags: java, urlclassloader, dynamic-class-loaders

```
   URLClassLoader child;
   try {
       child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myJar.toURI().toURL()}, Test2.class.getClassLoader());
       child.loadClass("com.bla.bla.StringUtilService");
   } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` in `loadClass`.

I have tried several variants of the code such as

```
URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + "E:\\Works\\Workspace\\JUnit_Proj\\client.jar"+"!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
```

But all results into `ClassNotFoundException`!

I have tried debugging in Eclipse, but the class loader instance is unable to load classes from the jar. The classes Vector is empty.

Comment: What is the type of `myJar`?

Comment: @Henry : java.io.File. Tried with JarFile as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeeded using different costructor of URLClassLoader.

```
    try {
        File jarFile = new File("D:\\Workspace\\Test\\Test.jar");
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jarFile.toURI().toURL()});

        Class.forName("com.bla.bla.HelloWorld", true, loader);
        System.out.println("Success");
        loader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is a direct child of the dir in the url, so you need no package.

**Try this without the package. Like this:**

```
URLClassLoader child;
try {
    child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myJar.toURI().toURL()}, Test2.class.getClassLoader());
    child.loadClass("StringUtilService");
} catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Also, try like this:**

```
URLClassLoader child;
try {
    child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{myJar.toURI().toURL()}, getClass().class.getClassLoader());
    child.loadClass("StringUtilService");
} catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Solution from:** [ClassNotFoundException while loading a class from file with URLClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685807/classnotfoundexception-while-loading-a-class-from-file-with-urlclassloader/24685919#24685919)

Comment: Anyone has successfully loaded classes from jars dynamically?

Comment: Read this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html